I have error users.map is not a function when I mapping the fetching data from api in nextjs
When I use console.log(users) to fetch data asynchronously from API in nextJS, users data console.log(users) works successfully in the console, but when I return the mapping data, it says users.map() is not a function.
Below is the code:
async function getUsers(){
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/users");
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

export default async function Page(){
    try{
        const users = await getUsers();
        console.log(users);
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>List of users</h1>
            {
                users.map( (item) => {
                    {item.name}
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

output:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: users is not defined

Source
src\app\users\page.js (19:17) @ users

  17 |             <h1>List of users</h1>
  18 |             {
> 19 |                 users.map( (item) => {
     |                 ^
  20 |                     {item.name}
  21 |                 })
  22 |             }

I am trying to fetch user's data from API to show the frontend.

You have a problem with the scope. users is declared inside the try block, so you can't reference it outside it. If you use it within the try block, you should be OK. E.g.:
export default async function Page() {
    try{
        const users = await getUsers();
        console.log(users);
   
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>List of users</h1>
                {
                    users.map( (item) => {
                        {item.name}
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // return some sensible default empty page here
    }

}


You don't need to use try to catch error
async function getUsers(){
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/users");
const data = await response.json();
return data;
}

export default async function Page(){
    const users = await getUsers();

    if(!users.ok){
    console.log("failed to fetch users data")
    }

return(
    <div>
        <h1>List of users</h1>
        {
            users.map( (item) => {
                {item.name}
            })
        }
    </div>
)
}

